# APNS strange feedback

Tags: iphone, sandbox, apple-push-notifications, feedback

Hi I'm getting strange feedback from the feedback sandbox server.

Actually there should be only my device registered so I expect always the same device token (which I already know).
Anyway... I'm getting every time a different device token and always the same timestamp "Wed Mar 04 02:46:40 +0100 1981"

Is that normal or is there something wrong with my code?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never got anything 'normal' out of the feedback service in the sandbox. It tends to be broken most of the time. For months it would never return anything at all - be glad you're getting something!

Comment: So you are saying this is "normal". The only way to test feedback would be in production with adhoc?

Comment: The time stamp for feedback, although reported isn't really important. The UDID's are. So in terms of testing... yes, it's perfectly normal. In production, any UDID given by feedback should be removed from your list (uninstalled application, reformatted phone etc.) - hope that helps.

Comment: It would be nice if it return some error information even it's dummy error data :) 
Bresc Lee is right, you should be glad for returning something from apple's feedback server. I haven't get anything.

Comment: Fwiw, I just personally discovered that the feedback service will spit out garbage data until it starts sending real feedback objects.

  That being said, you should eat up all bad data until you start seeing valid data, at which point you're getting actual feedback.